# Convert <table> to <div>

Tags: css, html

Do there is any converter available online to convert html code written with <table> tag to <div> ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do that automatically, See this link: http://www.adobe.com/support/dreamweaver/layout/tables_and_layers/tables_and_layers03.html

Comment: Yes there is: http://www.tabletodivconverter.com

Answer (score 2):

Possibly yes.

Should you use it though? No.

If you have non-tabular data using a `table` element you should change this to `div`/CSS for that **specific case**.

Any general converter will most probably produce worse code than if you stuck with the table element.

Kudos for wishing to convert your non-tabular data table elements, but if you wish to do this properly, learn how to code CSS yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not...

I don't think it's possible to just convert TABLEs to DIVs, they're two completely different things... You would need styling to at least have divs look slightly like tables and even then it can probably never be a full match without manual styling...

Comment: dreamweaver can do it.

Answer (score -1):

Tables and divs are two different beasts. A table holds tabular data a DIV is a generic container. So the answer is no.

See docs for  [Div](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/div) and [Table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/table)